# Ehcache with Spring Cache assigns wrong key

Tags: spring, caching, ehcache, spring-cache

I've got a method in UserService:

```
@Cacheable(value="user", key="#p0")
public User find(String name) {
    return userRepository.findOneByName(name);
}
```

And it caches. But then I try to get all keys from 'user' cache:

```
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance();
cacheManager.getCache("user").getKeys().forEach(o -> log.debug(o.toString()));
```

Output:

> com.cache.domain.User#1

Instead, for example, 'John Doe'.

Comment: Have you tried @Cacheable(value="user", key="#name") ?

Comment: Yes. It gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

See the Javadoc of `getKeys`

> Returns a list of all elements in the cache, whether or not they are expired.

That's actually returning the elements, no the ids. You may want to change your code to cast `o` to `Element` and output `getObjectKey()` instead.

You don't need to specify the `key` attribute. Since what you want is to use the single argument of your method (`name`) the cache abstraction will use that by default.