# Spring Cache with Ehcache @CacheEvict doesn't work

Tags: spring, ehcache, spring-cache

I've got next method in UserService:

```
@Cacheable(value = "user", key="#p0")
public User find(String user) {
    return userRepository.findByUser(User);
}
```

It caches well. In other service I have:

```
@Transactional
public void updateToken(int id, String token) {
    Group group = groupRepository.findOne(id);
    group.getMembers().forEach(member -> {
        member.getUser().setToken(token);
        removeUserCacheByName(member.getUser().getName());
    });
    groupRepository.save(group);
}

@CacheEvict(value = "user", key="#p0")
public void removeUserCacheByName(String name) {
    log.debug("Removing user cache by name {}.", name);
}
```

After updateToken method, cache does not clear.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14077831/1910582)

Comment: It looks like your configuration is <cache:annotation-driven mode="proxy" /> try <cache:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" />

Comment: I've tried @EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ) and it doesn't work too.

Comment: Try all entry eviction, this will help to isolate if there is any issues with key. @CacheEvict(value = "user", allEntries=true)

Comment: This is not the solution, because then there is no sense in cache at all in my case.

Comment: you are right. I believe there is some issue with the key setting, if it is confirmed we can look for options to solve the issues with key

Comment: It may refer to my [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581039/ehcache-with-spring-cache-assigns-wrong-key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing is normal. You're calling `removeUserCacheByName()` from within the Proxy object so the catching aspect doesn't execute. You have this behaviour explained in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies).

You can do some things to work around this:

1) Take the evict method (`removeUserCacheByName`) to another bean, autowire it in updateToken()'s class, and call it.

2) An ugly but useful one, autowire the ApplicationContext, get the same object from it and call the method, e.g.:

```
public class UserService{

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext ac;

    @Transactional
    public void updateToken(int id, String token) {
        Group group = groupRepository.findOne(id);
        group.getMembers().forEach(member -> {
            member.getUser().setToken(token);
            UserService sameBean = ac.getBean(UserService.class);
            sameBean.removeUserCacheByName(member.getUser().getName());
        });
        groupRepository.save(group);
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "user", key="#p0")
    public void removeUserCacheByName(String name) {
        log.debug("Removing user cache by name {}.", name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Both doesn't work for me. In the first case, I moved 'removeUserCacheByName' to UserService and invoked 'updateToken' from GroupService. In the second, I stored both methods together in one service. May it refer to my [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38581039/ehcache-with-spring-cache-assigns-wrong-key)?